# Applying mouse click listener for a dynamically created Text object in Java fxml application

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I just started to learn java fxml application development.
My goal is to show a fxml screen with random texts. So I implemented a CustomLabel class and generated the objects dynamically and the texts is showing in scene as i expected. Now I would like to apply mouse click listener on each label. I have tried with awt onClick listener but that not effected . I am searching for a better way of implementation. If anybody has any idea or if my implementation way is wrong in this scenario then please correct me.
Here I would like to show my customLabel class

```
 public class CustomLabel extends Text{

 public interface ChoseListener{
   void onChosed(String text);
 }
 private boolean onClicked = true;
 ChoseListener choseListener;
 private Random random = new Random();
 private int y = 0;

 public CustomLabel(ChoseListener choseListener,String text,int y){
   super(text);

   this.y = y;
   initLabel();
   startAnimation();
 }

 private void initLabel(){
   //here I would like to add mouseclick listener to this object
     //and I planed to call choseListener.onChosed(this.getText()) inside click listener so my scene can simply retrieve the text.
   this.setFont(new Font("Arial", 25));
 }

 void startAnimation(){
    this.setY(y);
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
    timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
    final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(this.xProperty(), 700);
    final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(9000), kv);
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
    timeline.play();
  }
 }
```

I have a factory class which will create a list of CustomLabel objects for a requested scene.
If custom text object can't archive this please let me know. I know very little about java basics. From my knowledge there is a way to add click listener to this object. If you get my problem help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void initLabel(){
    this.setFont(new Font("Arial", 25));
    this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> choseListener.onChosed(getText()) );
}
```

Comment: I learned a little bit about lambda expression in java. I haven't used ever. Its very simple. Thank you very much. you saved my day.